# Portuguese postal code

Tags: forms, input

What is the best solution for filling a portuguese postal code?
A mask input, or separate input fields?

The format for the portuguese postal code is [xxxx]-[xxx]
So what is best?

Input Mask
[xxxx-xxx] - The hyphen is there already, giving the help for the user.

Or

Separate Input Fields
[xxxx]-[xxx] - This is not very good to form validation, but its easier for users i think.

What do you think?
Thanks

Comment: What is it for? Desktop application? Mobile website? Responsive site? iPhone App? Different devices have more optimal input methods than others so if we know what you're targeting then we can suggest the ideal option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Brazil and I must say that having separated input fields is frustrating.

I would stick with the input mask. Users can type the postal code without having to worry about the hyphen or changing fields. Even if the fields change automatically, the input mask solution seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes i decided for the input mask. The only thing that i mentioned to the developers was the browse compatibility. Thanks